# localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop on my Mac machine.

When i try to run `./start-all.sh`

I run into the following error.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.1/libexec/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 58: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.1/libexec: is a directory
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as jiahaotan in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
Starting datanodes
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [jiahaos-MBP]
jiahaos-MBP: env: bash: No such file or directory
2021-07-28 01:23:39,198 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
resourcemanager is running as process 19761.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-jiahaotan-resourcemanager.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
```

I've tried everything from uninstalling and reinstalling and followed the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/beeranddiapers/installing-hadoop-on-mac-a9a3649dbc4d) but still could not find the issue.

Do i have to use the bash shell instead? (i'm using zsh)

Comment: Try not using `start-all`. Use `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` commands separately. If those work, then `start-yarn` (all in different terminals), but yes, the start script tries to use bash